# Write Select Case statement in VBA more briefly

Tags: excel-2016, vba7

Is it possible to write the following code in **VBA Excel 2016** more briefly?

```
Select Case NemberOfProduct(i)
    Case 1
    CounterPlot(1) = CounterPlot(1) + 1
    SumPureRate(1) = SumPureRate(1) + H(i)
    Case 2
    CounterPlot(2) = CounterPlot(2) + 1
    SumPureRate(2) = SumPureRate(2) + H(i)
    Case 3
    CounterPlot(3) = CounterPlot(3) + 1
    SumPureRate(3) = SumPureRate(3) + H(i)
.
.
   Case 12
    CounterPlot(12) = CounterPlot(12) + 1
    SumPureRate(12) = SumPureRate(12) + H(i)
    
End Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either manualy use `NemberOfProduct(i)` expresion as value.
So your whole `select case` could be replaced with

```vb
CounterPlot(NemberOfProduct(i)) = CounterPlot(NemberOfProduct(i)) + 1
SumPureRate(NemberOfProduct(i)) = SumPureRate(NemberOfProduct(i)) + H(i)
```

Or even more simplify it by storing `NemberOfProduct(i)` inside variable and then use it.

```vb
Dim n as Integer
n = NemberOfProduct(i)
CounterPlot(n) = CounterPlot(n) + 1
SumPureRate(n) = SumPureRate(n) + H(i)
```